# array.includes(element) is giving false only in Angular 8(typescript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am having an array as :

```
const ELEMENT_DATA: any[] =[
      {first:'1001', second:'john', third:'India'}, 
      {first:'1002', second:'Mack', third:'US'}]
```

Now, I want to check if my array is having an element named "first" or not. simply I want to get the names of elements only or just want to check if my array contains the required element or not in angular 8.

I have tried everything like `array.includes(arr)`, `array.find(arr=>....)`, `array.some(...)` etc. But for everything it's giving false value only. even if the element is present then also it's giving false only.

Comment: Do you want to check whether the array has an element with a key `first` or are you looking for a specific _value_ of `first`?

Comment: yes i am looking for  whether the array has an element with a key first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now, I want to check if my array is having an element named "first" or not

To check whether any of your array items has a key named `first` you should use `some`

```js
const ELEMENT_DATA = [
      {first:'1001', second:'john', third:'India'}, 
      {first:'1002', second:'Mack', third:'US'}];
      
var result = ELEMENT_DATA.some(e => Object.keys(e).includes('first'));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why isn't `some(e => e.first)` enough?

Comment: @CristianTraìna because if the value of `first` is falsey, then it will return false.

Comment: hey thanks Jamiec and Cristian both the answers worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, you want to check some element of array includes property "first". I could do it like this

```
const ELEMENT_DATA = [
      {first:'1001', second:'john', third:'India'}, 
      {first:'1002', second:'Mack', third:'US'}
];
      
var result = ELEMENT_DATA.some(e => e.hasOwnProperty('first'));

console.log(result);
```